# Running MacBook Pro without battery

Tags: macbook-pro, battery

My MacBook's (Pro 2105) batteries are swollen and there is no AppleStore available here, is it possible to disconnect the battery from the mainboard and use the machine until I find replacement batteries from third-party stores? I don't want them explode!

Here are the pictures of the batteries: 
[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I'm not here to answer if you can run it without the battery... as I have no idea.

---

I'd perhaps look no further than iFixit if I wanted to replace the battery myself. I'm not sure if this is your exact model, I just picked one that was close enough: https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/MacBook+Pro+15-Inch+Retina+Display+Mid+2015+Battery+Replacement/89284

You can typically buy the parts needed for the guide straight from them.

**Before you start ordering new batteries or disassembling it further...** Are you super sure it's not possible for you to let Apple handle it? Many countries (as far as I know) don't have apple stores but instead, they have "Apple authorized service providers" (or whatever they are called). It would be easy to not realize that these types of places exist in some cases. Sometimes the local store that sells Apple devices can handle the repairs as well. Not always.

Unfortunately, I can't give you a direct URL to a website where you can find your nearest service location(s) (it differs from country to country), you just have to find it through this website: **https://locate.apple.com/**

Make sure to click the country selection button on the top right.

**The path to the right place differs from country to country, but as I think this is the longest possible path I decided to write it down:**

> Each step is a new page

1. Click the box that says something like: "Service and Support"

   - It may at this point already ask you to enter a city or area code to locate the nearest service location(s).
2. In a grid of boxes with Apple devices choose Mac

   - You may then have to further select Macbook in a similar grid
3. In a grid of boxes with text and icons click the box that is something like "Repairs and physical damage",
4. You may then get 2 options. To call the local apple call center or enter city or area code to locate the nearest service location(s).

You may also have to enter the device serial key or login with your apple id at some point.

Comment: As I told there is no Apple Store available here in Iran so none of your options would work, iFixit does not have shipping to Iran as well as Apple.

Comment: I'd strongly second getting the battery replaced. I had the exact same swollen battery issue with my MacBook Pro 2015 model. I it got it replaced at an Authorised Apple Reseller and Service Provider. We don't have Apple Retail Store in our country. I learned that the battery is glued to the bottom case of the MacBook Pro and when replacing battery, technically your entire bottom case is replaced. You end up getting a new keyboard, trackpad and the unibody case. Your MacBook may be covered under Apple Care if you bought it.

Comment: Yes, you can run it without the battery. I would remove it sooner rather than later as the swelling can cause issues.

Comment: @Maysam, to be fair I didn't suggest there would be. We don't have any Apple Stores in Finland either. We do have those authorized service providers as I mentioned. I was hoping you would too. Maybe you could get the replacement battery from a local repair shop. You can't be the first ever Iranian to have had issues with their Apple devices... You'd think that there's some way to get it repaired. I'm sure you can get the batteries from Ebay but I'm not sure if I would trust those not to explode. Maybe there are some online communities in Iran that would be helpful in this matter.

Comment: I'll get a new replacement from China in like a month, I hope the current one works that long.